# Is it fine to present dichotomous variable as mean and SD

Tags: categorical-data, mean, standard-deviation

Is it statistically correct to present dichotomous variable as mean and SD in descriptive tables ? (ex: `Female mean(sd)` = 
 `(0.36 (0.48))`, `Stroke (mean (sd))` = `0.07 (0.25))` 
Is there any advantage on presenting it in mean and sd?

Answer (score 4):

In fact, you can present **only mean**, and it will fully describe the distribution of your variable.

If the variable is dichotomious, it means that in the fraction $p$ of observations it is `True`, and in the rest $(1-p)$ observations it is `False`. Its mean thus is exactly $p$, and SD is $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$.

For more clarity, you could add the number of observations. It would show, how reliably your sample mean estimates the "true" population proportion $p$.

Comment: Only mean *and* sample size, since we are talking about binomial distribution.

Comment: Quite correct, and +1, but I'd still say that summarizing a dichotomous variable using the mean and sample size is unfortunate. It reminds me of expressing my child's fever in [Kelvin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin) or [Réaumur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9aumur_scale) - yes, all the information is there, but it's needlessly complicated to understand.